# RESTful ASP.NET MVC3 Routing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, rest, routes

I've looked through the various questions already asked on this topic, and I've spent time trying to get it working how I would like it to, but I haven't had much luck so hopefully someone here can help me fill in the gaps.

With a new site I'm creating I wanted to try getting the URL structure to be more RESTful (I wanted to do it with my first MVC3 creations, but, time did not permit such experimenting).  However, I don't want the different URLs to all point to the same action.  I want different actions for each resource requested to keep the controller code concise and intuitive.

Here is an example of the URL structure I'm shooting for:

```
/Case   //This currently works
/Case/123   //This currently works
/Case/123/Comment   //This one does not work (404)
```

Here is how I currently have my routes setup:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Case",
    "Case/{id}",
    new { controller = "Case", action = "Number" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "CaseComment",
    "Case/{caseId}/Comment/{id}",
    new { controller = "Case", action = "CaseComment" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

The first two URL's I listed are worked correctly with this route structure.  The first URL takes me to my listing page.  When an id is specified, I hit the `Number` action so I can show details for that particular record.  The `Comment` URL is not working.

I have the action for the third URL defined as:

```
public ActionResult CaseComment(string caseId, string id) {
    //Narr
}
```

What am I missing?  And, could I set this up in an easier fashion for future resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to make the id parameter optional.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Case Resources",
    "Case/{caseId}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Case", action = "CaseComment", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe MapRoutes are order specfic, so

```
/Case/123/Comment
```

is using your

```
routes.MapRoute( 
  "Case", 
  "Case/{id}", 
  new { controller = "Case", action = "Number" });
```

route, thus throwing a 404.  Most specific route should be place above more general routes.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the CaseComment route above the Case route.

Answer (score 0):

Mapping routes are order specific.

One thing you may wish to consider for restful routing in MVC is a project called RestfulRouting that is on GitHub originally written by Steve Hodgekiss.

https://github.com/stevehodgkiss/restful-routing

If nothing else, looking at the code may well help you.

Hope this helps.